# Applying mask to field in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, masking

The data are stored in an Oracle database and I am using Oracle SQL developer. 
I am attempting to apply a mask to a data field that is stored without the mask. The desire is both to pull back the mask cell in some queries and to be able to sum the column in other.  The field is stored typically in NCPDP format for quantity as `00000000030000` (= `30`) or `00000000030000-` (= `-30`). The mask is `99999999999v999b:99999999999v999-`.

I have tried

```
select file_id,subm_quantity, to_char(subm_quantity,'99999999999v999b')
  from VALIUSER.ivd_transaction_record_details
 where file_id in (1123);
```

If possible I would prefer a dynamic masking, in which the individual mask is found with this method:

```
SELECT file_id, column_name, mask
  FROM valiuser.ivd_mapping m, valiuser.ivd_mapping_record mr
     , valiuser.ivd_mappingset ms, valiuser.ivd_transaction_file tf
 WHERE ms.mappingset_id = mr.mappingset_id
   AND mr.mapping_record_id = m.mapping_record_id
   AND tf.mappingset_id = ms.mappingset_id
   AND M.Column_Name = 'quantity'
   AND tf.file_id = 1123;
```

Comment: the column i am attempting to treat as  VARCHAR2 as a NUMBER

Comment: are you trying to print a string as a number, or are you trying to HIDE the value from end users by masking it via a hash or random value?

Comment: I am trying to print a sting as a number.  trying to move the negative sign to the front and add the decimal to the correct location. this is what is in the field  00000000030000-  i want -30.

Comment: Fun. I'd probably start by stripping all the leading zeros using a regexp into a virtual (derived) column. then for the last char being a (-) you could subtract that derived value from 0...someone here will come up with an elegant solution i'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Your mask isn't quite correct. First, I don't think the `V` does what you want it to; normally it multiplies by the number of digits following it, while you want division. Second, `B` doesn't denote the sign, `S` does.

So you want something like this:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('00000000030000-', '99999999999999S')/1000
 FROM dual;
```

Of course, this will fail on the value `00000000030000`, which doesn't have a trailing sign. You could maybe add one, conditionally, but a regular expression might be more workable in your case:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE('00000000030000-', '^(\d+)(-)?$', '\2\1'))/1000
  FROM dual;
```

This works with both of your example values. If you need to convert it to a `CHAR` (for whatever reason), do it after it's been converted to a number:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE('00000000030000-', '^(\d+)(-)?$', '\2\1'))/1000)
  FROM dual;
```